# jQuery CLNDR Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am using:
https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR

I have multiday calendar and in Firefox 28.0 (Win 7) [nor IE 9 nor IE10] PAST events won't display. E.g. I have 2 days event that started on 4th April and lasts until 5th of April. Today is 6th of April and in Firefox 4th and 5th are not marked as event ( also "event" class is not assigned to their "< td >" elements. Everything works great in Chrome.

Can you give me a helping hand?
Here is an example: http://wwiz.comyr.com/calendar/

Comment: I have the same issue.. I will upvote the thread.